# Why Does MetaMask Recommend Connecting Only Via User Action?

Tags: metamask

> You should **only** initiate a connection request in response to direct user action, such as clicking a button.

> You should **never** initiate a connection request on page load.

The latter is exactly what I'd prefer to do.  What could be their possible reasoning for strongly advising against this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users typically expect to click a button before logging on to any website. There are few websites that show a login dialog immediately as the first thing a user sees.

Comment: This makes sense, although MetaMask could have explained that briefly rather than scaring people into thinking there is some lurking security vulnerability in doing so

Comment: I looked up and their docs are open source and they might accept a PR with that suggestion: https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-docs/blob/master/docs/guide/getting-started.md#connecting-to-metamask

This is an example of an easy way to be a MetaMask contributor :)